# Angular SSR With .Net Core - add Cache-Control header for static HTML pages

Tags: angular, .net-core, angular-universal, cache-control

I have a project where I have 2 kinds of pages, Angular SSR pages, and MVC pages, I want to add Cache-Control header to Angular SSR pages Only (as they are static pages).

Is there a way I can do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `Cache-Control` header directly in your  `server.ts` file, e.g.:

```
res.header('Cache-control', 'public, max-age=300');
```